# Memory management in multiprocess python application on constrained device

Tags: python, memory-management, multiprocessing, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have a fairly constrained Ubuntu 20.04 host (256MB RAM) that is running into OOM errors after a few hours of running my python application. I ultimately solved this by manually calling `gc.collect()` in one subprocess but I want to know why and be sure this is the best solution.

I identified the process in my multiprocessing python application that was the dominant consumer of RAM and appeared to be growing consistently over time - suggesting a memory-leak.

I reduced the suspect process to a minimal example:

```
import pyogg
from pyogg import OpusBufferedEncoder
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import gc

def float32_to_int16(arr):
    arr = arr / np.max(np.abs(arr)) # scale to [-1.0,1.0]
    return (arr * (2**15 - 1)).astype(np.int16) # scale to int16 range

#initializes a numpy array of 720000 float_32 values
data32 = np.random.uniform(-1,1,720000).astype(np.float32) #10s of 48kHz sample rate mono audio

#converts the numpy array to int16
data16 = float32_to_int16(data32)

while True:
        print("loop")
        opus_buffered_encoder = OpusBufferedEncoder()
        opus_buffered_encoder.set_application("audio")
        opus_buffered_encoder.set_sampling_frequency(48000)
        opus_buffered_encoder.set_channels(1)
        opus_buffered_encoder.set_frame_size(20)

        ogg_opus_writer = pyogg.OggOpusWriter("test.opus", opus_buffered_encoder)
        ogg_opus_writer.write(memoryview(bytearray(data16)))
        ogg_opus_writer.close()

        time.sleep(5)
```

I confirmed with this minimal implementation that the OOM errors continued in the multiprocess context. Then I broke it out and ran it as a single-process application like shown above - it reproduced the ballooning RAM but before all available system RAM was exhausted it got garbage collected and no OOM error occurred. I added `gc.collect()` to the end of the loop and consumption stabilized, suggesting no actual memory leak present.

I then added the collection call to this same location in the original multiprocess code and the OOM errors have vanished.

Questions:

1. isn't the OS supposed to trigger GC in one python process when memory is requested by another python process and that isn't otherwise available?
2. is there likely something wrong with my code or pyogg (which wraps C libraries) that's resulting in GC not being automatic? How can I approach determining this (full application too much to post here)?
3. Instead of forcing garbage collection should I consider spawning a new process in the while loop to write each opus file?

Comment: Not determinate, but you could `del data32` as soon as you are done with it.

Comment: I think this is a good candidate for a new process since you are on a forking operating system. gc_collect at the end of the loop is interesting. Python frees memory to its own pools (not the OS) when its refcount goes to zero regardless of gc. gc is there to catch circular references that keep refcount alive. That's a good hint that the ogg / opus stuff is doing something strange. Close the encoder if it has a `close` method and `del` both of them at the end of the loop before gc to see what effect that has.

Comment: Also try putting your memoryview in a context manager `with memoryview(bytearray(data16)) as mem: ...`. That way the memory view will release the underlying buffer. It may not do that on refcount going to zero (I don't see a `__del__` method).